# Simplifying intersection of 3 sets when 2 are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intersection-theory

I am working on a problem involving the probability of the intersection of 3 sets:

$P(A \cap B \cap C)$, and am wondering if this can be simplified at all, since we are also given that the sets $A$ and $B$ are independent, so that, $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$, however, independence of either set with $C$ cannot be assumed.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot simplify it.

Comment: The next term is $P(A\cap C|B)\cdot P(B)$.